# arrow is not supported when using file-based collect, while conversion from pandas to spark and vice versa

Tags: pyspark, databricks, pyarrow, pyspark-pandas

I am trying to use arrow by

```
enabling spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true"), but getting following error 

 /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:340: UserWarning: createDataFrame 
 attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to 
 true; however, failed by the reason below:
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/local_disk0/spark-0419ce26-a5d1-4c8a-b985- 
 55ca5737a123/pyspark-f272e212-2760-40d2-9e6c-891f858a9a48/tmp92jv6g71'
 Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to 
 true.
 warnings.warn(msg)
 /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:161: UserWarning: toPandas 
 attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to 
 true, but has reached the error below and can not continue. Note that 
'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect on failures in 
 the middle of computation.
 arrow is not supported when using file-based collect
 warnings.warn(msg)
 Exception: arrow is not supported when using file-based collect
```

Our cluster version is 10.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12), driver type is standard_E32_V3

below is the code which I have tried to use from documentation [documentation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395351/arrow-is-not-supported-when-using-file-based-collect-while-conversion-from-pand)

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 # Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")

 # Generate a Pandas DataFrame
 pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3))

 # Create a Spark DataFrame from a Pandas DataFrame using Arrow
 df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

 # Convert the Spark DataFrame back to a Pandas DataFrame using Arrow
 result_pdf = df.select("*").toPandas()
```